# Move values of cell to next column if integer

Tags: excel, vba, formula

I haven't used formulas in Excel before. Currently, the values of my cells are misaligned. What I would like to do is move the values of column F to column G if they are numerical values. For instance, in the 7th row that is displayed in my image, I'd like to move 48 over to the adjacent cell to the right. Same with 3054, 5770, and 32. However, I DON'T want to move IsCallOnly because it is an alphanumerical value. How would I go about doing this? Thanks!

[image: example of issue]

Answer (score 1):

In cell G2, try:

```
 =IF(ISNUMBER(F2),F2,"")
```

This will tell is to copy the adjacent cell if it is a number, but leave the cell blank if it is not.

Comment: Hi user3700285, thank you very much for the reply! It seems promising! I do have one (probably very trivial) followup question. How do I apply the formula you have so that it works for an entire column? That is, I want G2 to take on the value of F2, and G3 to take on the value of F3 - how does one "generalize" the formula you have above? I am a complete Excel n00b, apologies in advance!

Comment: If I understand your question, one your formula is in the desired column, highlight the cell and drag it down to fill the cells below. Is that what you're asking?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest, in H1 and copied down:

```
=IF(G1="",F1,G1)
```

this looks to see if G1 is empty and if it is, take F1, otherwise take G1.

However, the number values in ColumnF are copied rather than moved, though it could be arranged for 'move' rather than 'copy, if required, with a bit of fiddling.

Neither requires VBA but if that is obligatory then it would help if you would post the code you have tried so far.

Comment: You could use a very similar approach to generate a new column with just the values you want from column F too.  e.g. create a new column with the formula `=if(isnumber(f1),"",f1)`.  Logic being if there is a word in column F you want to keep it, if there is a number you don't want it (as @pnuts has already shown how to extract these)

Comment: Hi pnuts and Texas, thank you very much for the reply! The response you've posted certainly seems promising. I will test it out on my Excel sheet. As a followup, though, do you know how to "generalize" the formula you have above so that it can be applied to an entire column? I am a complete Excel n00b, apologies in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are asking to move only the numbers in column F to column G?, if so maybe the following will help.

```
Sub MoveMyNumbers()

    MoveNumbers "XXX", "F"

End Sub
```

.

```
Function MoveNumbers(ShtName As String, ColLetter As String)
Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
Dim ColNumber As Integer
Dim lRow As Long
Dim i As Long

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ShtName)
    lRow = ws.Range(ColLetter & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

   'Get Column Number from column letter
    ColNumber = ws.Range(ColLetter & "1").Column

    For i = 1 To lRow
        If IsNumeric(Cells(i, ColNumber).Value) Then 
           Cells(i, (ColNumber + 1)).Value = Cells(i, ColNumber).Value
           Cells(i, ColNumber).Value = " "
        End IF
    Next i
   End Function
```